# How do I test a directive with extra parameters?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I'm trying to test a directive with a constant (ie, `SEARCH_URL`) that is injected in:

```
.directive('autocomplete', [
  "$rootScope",
  "SEARCH_URL",
  function (
    $rootScope,
    SEARCH_URL
  ) {
  // ...
});
```

with this test:

```
describe('autocomplete directive', function () {
  "use strict";

  var element, scope;

  beforeEach(module('nav'));

  beforeEach(function() {
    inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      var linkingFn = $compile("<div ng-model='search' autocomplete></div>");
      scope = $rootScope;
      element = linkingFn(scope);
    });
  });

  it('selection resets autocomplete matches', function() {
    scope.select({ Title: "Something" });
    expect(scope.autocompleteMatches.length).toEqual(0);
  });
});
```

However, I'm not sure where to inject the constant in the test. I get this error when I run the test

```
PhantomJS 1.9 (Mac) autocomplete directive selection resets autocomplete matches FAILED
    Error: Unknown provider: SEARCH_URLProvider <- SEARCH_URL <- autocompleteDirective
        at /Users/ttt/Work/Dev/az/az-search-html/app/public/vendor/angular-unstable/angular.min.js:29
```

In another test for a controller, I am able to inject extra parameters with something like

```
$controller('ArticleCtrl', params);
```

How do I do that for directives?

Answer (score 2):

You can use angular.mocks to stub the constant like this:

```
  beforeEach(function() {
    module(function($provide) {
      $provide.constant('SEARCH_URL', 'my seach url');
    });
  });
```